# The supplied credentials '{0'} cannot be used to sign request

Tags: azure-storage

While using Shared Access Signature to fetch Table data using StorageClient Library 2.0, I am consistently getting the error "The supplied credentials '{0'} cannot be used to sign request". From GitHub what I can understand is that the error is due to sasCredentials.CanSignRequest returning false...but as per code in GitHub there are no scenarios where it is supposed to return true...is it a bug...or am I doing something wrong here?

StorageCredentials sasCredentials = new StorageCredentialsSharedAccessSignature(sharedAccessSignature);
CloudTableClient ctc = new CloudTableClient(tableEndpoint, sasCredentials);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[StorageCredentialsSharedAccessSignature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/microsoft.windowsazure.storagecredentialssharedaccesssignature.aspx) type does not exist in Azure Storage Client Library 2.0. Hence, I am assuming you are still using an older version, most probably 1.7. As also described in the [Introducing Table SAS (Shared Access Signature), Queue SAS and update to Blob SAS](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2012/06/12/introducing-table-sas-shared-access-signature-queue-sas-and-update-to-blob-sas.aspx) blog post, support for Table SAS was added in newer releases of the Azure Storage Client Library.

I strongly recommend upgrading to 2.0, which also has many other improvements in addition to the functionality you are looking for. For more details, please refer to [Introducing Windows Azure Storage Client Library 2.0 for .NET and Windows Runtime](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2012/10/29/introducing-windows-azure-storage-client-library-2-0-for-net-and-windows-runtime.aspx).